# Retrieval of annotations of genes across multiple datasets using biomaRt

Tags: r

I have a list of genes (Entrenz_IDs: link https://www.dropbox.com/s/phjxkutm3xv2fi6/Ids.csv?dl=0). I want some annotations of these genes across many datasets (e.g.. human, zebra fish, etc.). I am trying this using biomaRt.

The code I tried is;

```
library(biomaRt)

ensembl=useMart("ensembl")
datasets <- listDatasets(ensembl)

genes <- read.csv(file = file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = ",")

GOannotations <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(datasets)) {
       for (j in (genes)) {
            values <- genes$genes[j]
            GOannotations[[i]] <- getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", "name_1006", "peptide"),
                          filters = "ensembl_gene_id",
                          values = values,
                          mart = useMart(biomart = "ensembl", dataset = datasets$dataset[i])
           }
     }
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error in checkAtAssignment("Mart", "dataset", "AsIs") : 
assignment of an object of class “AsIs” is not valid for @‘dataset’ in an object of class “Mart”; is(value, "character") is not TRUE
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there any other way by which I can do this?

Comment: maybe add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the call to `data.frame()`?

Comment: @MartinMorgan: It dint work. The same error message is popping.

Comment: The problem seems to be the class of `values`, so if `class(values)` does not return "character" then that points to the problem that needs to be fixed

Comment: @MartinMorgan: how can I fix it?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, so I can't tell what the problem is. You have to figure it out for yourself, or make your example fully reproducible (e.g., by using one of the data sets included with R, or by making your object `ensembl` and the file you choose with read.csv() available via some file sharing service.

Comment: @MartinMorgan: I have added the link to the input file and declared my ensemble mart. Is it clear now? or do I have to specify anything else?

Comment: I don't know why, but `class(datasets$dataset[i])` returns "AsIs", instead of "character", you could use `datasets$dataset[[i]]`. Do you need the inner for loop, or is it enough to look for `values=genes$genes` (look up all genes at once).

Comment: @MartinMorgan: I did try using datasets$dataset[[i]] and also by removing the inner loop, but o success.

Answer (score 0):

I set up biomaRt like this

```
library(biomaRt)
datasets <- listDatasets(useMart("ensembl"))
```

Then read in the data, ensuring that character strings were not interpreted as factors

```
## file <- file.choose()
file <- "~/Downloads/Ids.csv"
genes <- read.csv(file = file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I then wrote a function that will take one dataset, the genes of interest, and the mart, and query biomart. I put `getBM()` inside a `tryCatch()`, which means that it might fail but the function will still return a value (NULL).

```
fun <- function(dataset, values, ensembl) 
{
    stopifnot(is.character(dataset), is.character(genes))
    message(dataset)
    tryCatch({
        getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", "name_1006", "peptide"),
              filters = "ensembl_gene_id", values = values,
              mart = useMart(biomart = "ensembl", dataset = dataset))
    }, error=function(err) {
        message("data set '", dataset, "' failed: ", conditionMessage(err))
        NULL
    })
}
```

I tested my function, and it 'works', in the sense that biomart is queried, and a result is returned.

```
> fun("hsapiens_gene_ensembl", genes$genes, ensembl)
hsapiens_gene_ensembl
[1] ensembl_gene_id name_1006       peptide        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Obviously it doesn't work in terms of returning meaningful results, but that is a topic for a different question (are `genes$genes` ensembl gene ids, as advertised in the `filters=` argument?).

To process many datasets, I wrote

```
GOannotations <-
    lapply(as.character(datasets$dataset), fun, genes$genes, ensembl)
```